# Cannot deserialize from XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a fixed, valid XML document. I'm trying to deserialize it in order to get an object hierarchy. However there's an exception being thrown.

This is my XML document:

```
<ROWSET>
   <ROW>
      <LOT>LOT1234</LOT>
      <DATE_TRANS>2012-05-20</DATE_TRANS>
      <NUMERO_AA227>AA227_001</NUMERO_AA227>
      <NUMERO_ETUI>ETUI_001</NUMERO_ETUI>   
      <IDENTITE_BOITE_1>Boite1_1</IDENTITE_BOITE_1>
      <IDENTITE_BOITE_2>Boite1_2</IDENTITE_BOITE_2>
      <IDENTITE_BOITE_3>Boite1_3</IDENTITE_BOITE_3>
      <IDENTITE_BOITE_4>Boite1_5</IDENTITE_BOITE_4>
      <IDENTITE_BOITE_5>Boite1_5</IDENTITE_BOITE_5>
   </ROW>
   <ROW>
      <LOT>LOT5678</LOT>
      <DATE_TRANS>2012-05-20</DATE_TRANS>
      <NUMERO_AA227>AA227_001</NUMERO_AA227>
      <NUMERO_ETUI>ETUI_001</NUMERO_ETUI>   
      <IDENTITE_BOITE_1>Boite1_1</IDENTITE_BOITE_1>
      <IDENTITE_BOITE_2>Boite1_2</IDENTITE_BOITE_2>
      <IDENTITE_BOITE_3>Boite1_3</IDENTITE_BOITE_3>
      <IDENTITE_BOITE_4>Boite1_5</IDENTITE_BOITE_4>
      <IDENTITE_BOITE_5>Boite1_5</IDENTITE_BOITE_5>
   </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

And this is my object model:

```
[Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("DTOFournitureListeImporter")]
public class DTOFournitureListeImporter
{
   [XmlArray("ROWSET")]
   [XmlArrayItem("ROW", typeof(DTOFournitureImporter))]
   public DTOFournitureImporter[] dtoFournitureImporter { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class DTOFournitureImporter
{
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("lot")]
   public string lot { get; set; }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("date_trans")]
   public DateTime date_trans { get; set; }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("numero_aa227")]
   public string numero_aa227 { get; set; }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("numero_etui")]
   public string numero_etui { get; set; }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("identite_boite_1")]
   public string identite_boite_1 { get; set; }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("identite_boite_2")]
   public string identite_boite_2 { get; set; }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("identite_boite_3")]
   public string identite_boite_3 { get; set; }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("identite_boite_4")]
   public string identite_boite_4 { get; set; }

   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("identite_boite_5")]
   public string identite_boite_5 { get; set; }
}
```

How I deserialize:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DTOFournitureListeImporter));
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(model.cheminFichierXML);
DTOFournitureListeImporter dTOFournitureListeImporter = (DTOFournitureListeImporter)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
textReader.Close();
```

And the error:

> There is an error in XML document (2, 2). -
>   System.InvalidOperationException: was not expected.
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDTOFournitureListeImporter.Read4_DTOFournitureListeImporter()

Comment: Hello, please post your question in english! Not everyone speaks French here. Ce site est anglophone, posez votre question en anglais svp.

Comment: Pouvez-vous mettre cela en anglais?

Comment: You can use Google Translate to translate your question.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but you should try to write in english. What will happen if I start to write in Italian and someone else in Spanish or Deutsch? (at least try to, there are many people here who can correct your text ... and mine :-)  )

Comment: Ik begrijp deze vraag niet, want hij is geschreven in het Frans. Kun je hem alsjeblieft vertalen naar het Engels, zodat ik hem begrijp en ik je misschien kan helpen?

Comment: Don't close this, I'm translating it into stranglish.

Comment: Bienvenue sur Stack Overflow! Malheureusement, SO est un site anglophone, et les questions doivent être écrites dans un anglais correct.

Comment: @Cicada: I closed it... and I reopened it. You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The problem could be that all the tags in the XML file are in capital letters, but the attributes in your class suggest they should be in small letters.

Also, you're saying in the attributes that the XML root is `DTOFournitureListeImporter`, which is not the case. The XML root is `ROWSET`.

So all in all: The structure you're trying to create does not match the XML file.

Comment: +1 The exact error message if you run this code is `<ROWSET xmlns=''> was not expected.`